# How can I use a variable for the label numer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use a variable for the label (or any other object as button, checkbox, etc.) number?
I need to change the color of a label. But the number of the label differs and is read in from an array.
So I need a way to change the number of the label in code.
Like:

```
Label & lablenr.forecolor = Color.red
```

or

```
Me.Controls("label" & labelnr).ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: what happens/fails when you try the second one?  You should turn on Option Strict

Comment: Your second example is the answer.

Comment: But the second example/answer is not working for me. The color of the label isn't changed. No error message

Comment: Correction: As this was running inside a Try...Catch section, I did not get an error. 
Outside this section it throughs out this error: "The objectreference is not assigned to an object instance" (translated to english). Any idea?
If I use the same command in a new project it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Correct error is called: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Ihave narrowed it down. All my labels are shown on a tab control. As soon as I create a label outside the tab control, the above solution is working. Any label inside the tabs through out the exception. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

`Me.Controls.Find("label" & labelnr, true)` basically.

Test whether one is found before you try to access ForeColor